# Can't show username on javaFx dashboard view

Tags: java, javafx, authentication, controller

i want to access method getUsername for username profile on dashboard from userField to view after login. but method make some error after login on Login controller. Thankss

MainApp

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(500.0);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
```

}

LoginController

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable  {
public MLogin loginModel = new MLogin();
@FXML
private Label status;
@FXML
private JFXTextField userField;
@FXML
private JFXPasswordField passField;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
}
@FXML
public void Login (ActionEvent event) throws IOException   {

    try {
        if (loginModel.isLogin(userField.getText(), passField.getText())) {

            ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/App.fxml").openStream());
            AppController appCtrl = (AppController)fxmlLoader.getController();
            appCtrl.GetUser(userField.getText());
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
            primaryStage.show();

        } else {
            status.setText("Username atau password anda salah");
        }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          status.setText("Username atau password anda salah");
      } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@FXML
private void Close(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Login model

```
public class MLogin {
Connection conection;
public MLogin() {
    conection = Connections.Mysql();
    if(conection == null) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public boolean isDbConnected() {
    try {
        return !conection.isClosed();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isLogin(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?";
    try {
        ps = conection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
    }
```

}
}

Login FXML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="loginBg" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="989.0" stylesheets="@../styles/mainStyle.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.xaxxis.controller.LoginController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="535.0" prefWidth="760.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="726.0">
               <children>
                  <AnchorPane prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="668.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutX="32.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="283.0" text="Xaxxis Project" textFill="#eeebeb">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="40.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label layoutX="32.0" layoutY="80.0" text="Manda Putra System Information" textFill="#e8e6e6">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="21.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <AnchorPane layoutX="410.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="296.0" prefWidth="273.0" style="-fx-background-color: #050f1a;" styleClass="loginPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="40.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="273.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="242.218994140625" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="139.78271484375" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="141.17401123046875" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="133.21728515625" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                                 <children>
                                    <JFXTextField fx:id="userField" alignment="CENTER" focusColor="#0b9bd7" labelFloat="true" maxWidth="253.0" minWidth="253.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="253.0" promptText="Username" unFocusColor="#f8f6f6" />
                                    <JFXPasswordField fx:id="passField" focusColor="#0b9bd7" labelFloat="true" maxWidth="253.0" minWidth="253.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="253.0" promptText="Password" unFocusColor="#fcfcfc" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                 </children>
                              </GridPane>
                              <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="210.0" onAction="#Login" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="88.0" ripplerFill="#d3cbcb" style="-fx-background-color: #0B9BD7;" text="Login" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="38.0" />
                              <Label layoutX="16.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="198.0" text="Login to System" textFill="#f5f5f5">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="25.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="63.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="249.0" text="Enter your username and password to log on:" textFill="WHITESMOKE">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="11.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="147.0" layoutY="210.0" onAction="#Close" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="88.0" ripplerFill="#d3cbcb" style="-fx-background-color: #0B9BD7;" text="Cancel" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="38.0" />
                              <Label fx:id="status" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="250.0" textFill="#fc0d0d" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="18.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="267.0" />
                              <ImageView fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="37.0" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="15.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../icon/lock.png" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                              <Text fill="#fcfafa" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="37.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome" wrappingWidth="102.99127197265625">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Text>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="197.0" fitWidth="196.0" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="116.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="47.7">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../images/rocket.gif" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
                  <Label text="Copyright by Zaki Ibrahim" textFill="#eee8e8">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

AppControler

```
public class AppController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label userLabel; 

    @FXML
    private MenuButton userAcc;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        }    
    public void GetUser(String user) {
        // TODO
        userLabel.setText(user);
    }
 }
```

App FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="900.0" stylesheets="@../styles/Application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.xaxxis.controller.AppController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="767.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
               <left>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="headerLine" prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="229.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="534.0" prefViewportHeight="678.0" prefViewportWidth="128.0" prefWidth="193.0" translateX="1.0" translateY="1.0" translateZ="1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="59.0">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane prefHeight="534.0" prefWidth="225.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <MenuButton fx:id="usrAcc" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="79.0" prefWidth="225.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                      <items>
                                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false">
                                             <graphic>
                                                <AnchorPane prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="140.0">
                                                   <children>
                                                      <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="100.0" radius="45.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                                      <Label text="User Profile" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="110.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                                         <font>
                                                            <Font name="System Bold" size="19.0" />
                                                         </font>
                                                      </Label>
                                                      <Label fx:id="userLabel" text="Username" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="110.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
                                                      <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" style="-fx-background-color: #373737;" text="Logout.." textFill="#fcfafa" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="22.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0" />
                                                   </children>
                                                </AnchorPane>
                                             </graphic>
                                          </MenuItem>
                                      </items>
                                       <graphic>
                                          <AnchorPane prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="175.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="33.0" radius="30.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
                                                <Label fx:id="userLabel" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Username" textFill="#f8f8f8">
                                                   <font>
                                                      <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
                                                   </font>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Label layoutX="62.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="43.0" text="Online" textFill="#0f832e" underline="true" />
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </graphic>
                                    </MenuButton>
                                    <Separator layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="226.0" />
                                    <JFXButton alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="8.0" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="82.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="227.0" ripplerFill="#2aa0e7" style="-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;" text="Home" textFill="#f5f5f5">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="21.0" />
                                       </font>
                                       <graphic>
                                          <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="52.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                             <image>
                                                <Image url="@../icon/computer.png" />
                                             </image>
                                          </ImageView>
                                       </graphic></JFXButton>
                                    <JFXButton alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="13.0" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="125.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="227.0" style="-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;" text="Purchasing" textFill="#f5f5f5">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="21.0" />
                                       </font>
                                       <graphic>
                                          <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="52.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                             <image>
                                                <Image url="@../icon/purchase.png" />
                                             </image>
                                          </ImageView>
                                       </graphic>
                                    </JFXButton>
                                    <JFXButton alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="13.0" layoutY="174.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="227.0" style="-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT;" text="Opname" textFill="#f5f5f5">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="21.0" />
                                       </font>
                                       <graphic>
                                          <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="52.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                             <image>
                                                <Image url="@../icon/opname.png" />
                                             </image>
                                          </ImageView>
                                       </graphic>
                                    </JFXButton>
                                 </children></AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                        <GridPane prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="229.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="110.31568145751953" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="64.64358520507812" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="164.35641479492188" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="164.35641479492188" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <ToggleButton fx:id="sideMenuBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="43.0" translateX="5.0" translateY="5.0">
                                       <graphic>
                                          <ImageView fitHeight="38.0" fitWidth="36.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                             <image>
                                                <Image url="@../icon/3%20bar.png" />
                                             </image>
                                          </ImageView>
                                       </graphic>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </left>
               <center>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="565.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                     <top>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="538.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="538.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                <columnConstraints>
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                              </GridPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                     </top>
                  </BorderPane>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

My error:

```
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.xaxxis.controller.LoginController.Login(LoginController.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:693)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:37)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:763)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 63 more
```

on Line 57 Login Controller

```
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/App.fxml").openStream());
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question so it contains the complete stack trace: the beginning part of it is missing.

Comment: This all your code,  I don't see how do start your app!

Comment: Also, since the error seems to occur when loading `App.fxml`, you should probably also post the FXML file.

Comment: sorry. i'm newbie in java and javafx. now i'm done edited and post all my code

Comment: @Xaxxis What happened to the stack trace?

Comment: error on Line 57  At Login Controller
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/App.fxml").openStream());

Comment: @James_D null/../icon/computer.png javafx.fxml.LoadException: unknown path:75 just it, and im using maven

Comment: Can you [edit] the question so the stack trace is complete. The question is meaningless to other users without seeing the actual error message: that's the part that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: Im done edited the question @James_D , if the question is meaningless again you can suggest me what the question for this thread and i'll edit the question. Thanks james

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [location resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution) to load the image:

```
<Image url="@../icon/computer.png" />
```

This will only work if the `FXMLLoader` has a `location` set. However, since you use the `load(...)` method taking an input stream, and never specify the location, the `FXMLLoader` cannot resolve locations relative to the location of the FXML file (as far as the loader is concerned, there may not even be a file if you do things this way).

So instead, specify the location and use the no-argument `load()` method:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/App.fxml"));
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

Note that you can also abbreviate the first two lines to

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/App.fxml"));
```

Comment: Horay, i'm verry big thanks @James_D, myproblem is resolved